# Using Flask-Security as part of a REST API

Tags: rest, flask, wtforms, flask-security

The [Flask-Security docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/features.html#json-ajax-support) mention JSON/Ajax support for all of the important view endpoints. So it's possible to get all of the buit-in Flask-Security awesomeness by hitting the views with JSON objects.

But, now I'm trying to use it as part of a RESTful API, and it's not working, because it needs a CSRF token, which is necessary for webpages, but not for APIs:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 400
    },
    "response": {
        "errors": {
            "csrf_token": [
                "CSRF token missing"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using a REST API, the prefered method is token based authentication with something like JSON Web Token (JWT). This scheme has a different security landscape because you are not generating HTML on the server side or using cookies. I'm not a security expert, but from what I've read, this means you are not susceptible to Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF). This is why turning off CSRF tokens in Flask-Security is ok.

Try using PyJWT token based authentication scheme. To get the token, you post credentials to the 'login' endpoint and receive a token in response. You will then have to send the token with each request through HTTP headers. You can often set this globally on the JS side.

Here are a few references:

- http://jwt.io/
- https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/  (see note below)
- [Combining Flask-restless, Flask-security and regular Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186694/combining-flask-restless-flask-security-and-regular-python-requests)
- https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/
- https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/
- https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/python
- https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/
- https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/

note: It seems that Flask-JWT uses the python `itsdangerous` library which hasn't been updated in awhile. There is a discussion here: https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt/issues/10  Again, I'm not a security expert and both libraries seem to be handle the encoding/decoding by default with the same algorithm. PyJWT and Python-Jose are both listed on jwt.io and have extended functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, figured it out. All it needs is a Flask config variable to be set for the app:

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

Comment: How does this affect your main app?  Does it reduce security of the website?

Comment: Most probably not something what must be used. This document might help for other users coming here: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csrf.html#ajax